# [With FiWARE CEP]Can Kafka broker be used in place of Orion Context Broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

Can Kafka broker be used in place of Orion Context Broker with FIWARE CEP?
If yes, can anyone please share some links/documentation where I can get the information to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orion Context Broker is the core of the FIWARE platform. It defines a data model and a set of operations on such a data, NGSI, that somehow influences all other components of the platform. It is the case of the CEP, which has been designed for receiving NGSI notifications from Orion CB.

Being said that, there is always a way of adapting FIWARE components in order to use them in a way they were not originally designed.

In the case of Kafka+FIWARE CEP, if you are able to send data from Kafka to FIWARE CEP in a way the data emulates a NGSI notification, you'll be able to integrate them.

Anyway, you must notice Orion CB and Kafka are very different things. The former one does not implement queues, while the latter does. Orion imposes a data model (as said, NGSI), while Kafka does not...